# Why does JOptionPane.showInputDialog not require a parent component argument, but JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog does?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

JOptionPane.showInputDialog has a form that requires no parent component argument. JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog does. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> JOptionPane.showInputDialog has a form that requires no parent component argument. JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog does.

From [`showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent,Object message)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29)

> `parentComponent` - determines the Frame in which the dialog is displayed; **if null, or if the `parentComponent` has no Frame, a default Frame is used**

So..

> Why is this?

It isn't.

Comment: Still, it's not logical that you have to explicitly enter "null" with a messagedialog for example, and that you don't for an input dialog.

Comment: @SimonBaars There are 6 methods for showing an input dialog, two of which don't need a parent. There are only 3 methods in total for a message dialog. ***I*** think the latter is more logical, but for the actual logic of that, you'd have to ask the designers (the people that wrote the option pane).

Comment: Yea I guess, but to me it just looks like bad design. It's not so hard to just include a method that only requires a String and just calls the showMessageDialog with parameter null for parent instead of instructing in the javadoc for the users to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Because sometimes the programmer will want to allow the user to refer to the parent component to get a value of some kind for a showInputDialog. However, the showConfirmDialog is just a message that the user reads and then discards.

Comment: I guess I still don't understand. It is possible to set the parent component to null. The documentation just says that it's used to setup the dialog's frame, and if null, a default frame is used. I'm just surprised that there wasn't a method that didn't include the parent component and passed null to whatever method eventually gets called.

Comment: Yeah, you are understand it. With issues like this, I just assume that the creators of the Java library just didn't find it feasible to put it in. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

We show confirm dialog to get a confirmation from user on his action on a parent window.
Eg: User trying to close the main window is asked whether he really wants to close it??  or Pressing a delete button will ask for a confirmation on a delete operation

In short, by showing a confirm dialog we make user aware of any critical operation he wants to perform  on the parent window and ask for his confirmation for the same.

This is generally not the case with Input dialogs!